# How do I get the offsetHeight of an element in a parent component from the children?

Tags: angular

I need to get the offsetHeight of the content `<div>` defined in the parent component (base layout) from my child component, so I can make another `<div>` with the same size.

I tried like this but got `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`.

Here's the layout component:

```
  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="main" #mainContentArea>

    <!-- Breadcrumb -->
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <app-breadcrumbs></app-breadcrumbs>
    </ol>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div><!-- /.conainer-fluid -->
  </div>
```

And the child component typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class PmsSyncComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private elRef:ElementRef
  ) { }

  @ViewChild('mainContentArea') elementView: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    alert(this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeighta);
  }

}
```

Is this possible? I need to make this container the same size of the content area to implement the drag and drop feature for file upload.

Comment: Couldn't you just do it with css? Set the `<div class="main">` to relative and take up all width / height with you child component. The `mainContentArea` is not a child of your component. this can't work. you could use your `elRef` to get a hold of your parent like `this.elRef.parentNode`

Comment: You're right, for this case I can do this with CSS, but how can I have access to elements of a parent company?

Comment: I posted an answer, hope i could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i said in the commments, you could easily do this with CSS, but you said you want to get access to the parent element:

You can do this by accessing the `parentNode` of the `nativeElement` of your `ChildComponent` like this (simplified):

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) { 
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.parentNode.offsetHeight);
}
```

Make sure you use it in your `ngAfterViewInit`. It would still work in `ngOnInit` but if your parent Component would have other child components as well, it probably will cause problems, because they don't initialize at the same time and your `height` could differ.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To get parent you would need to use your attribute that you declared in your constructor like this:

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement.offsetHeight;
```